# Give an example of a bijection from R to (0,1). A sketch graph that clearly indicates the key features of your example will suffice.

Tags: functions

Question:

Give an example of a bijection from R to (0,1). A sketch graph that clearly indicates the key features of your example will suffice.

Where I am at so far:

I'm struggling with answering this question just by giving an example of a bijection.
Is there an easy an easy bijection from R to (0,1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the $\arctan$ function which takes $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and shift it accordingly:
$$\frac 1\pi \arctan(x) + \frac 12$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\to\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ works.

Answer (score 0):

The odd function $\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ bijects $\Bbb R$ to $(-1,\,1)$, so we can take $\frac12\left(1+\frac{x}{1+|x|}\right)$.